# what is the default mode of 'ofstream' in C++, binary or text?

Tags: c++

```
std::ofstream of(filename.c_str())
of << "contents" << std::endl;
```

Is the default mode binary of text?

Comment: As the writer of the accepted  answer for the dupe, which perhaps doesn't make things completely clear, it's text mode.

Comment: @NeilButterworth maybe you could edit that answer to make it completely clear :)

Comment: @M.M Reviewing it, I can't think how to make it clearer, only longer.